# Trouble with aligning items

Tags: html, css

Hello so while creating a site I've been working on I've ran into a problem. I have a link and next to it I have an image. The link is aligning the text in the link with the bottom of the image. I would like the surrounding box around the link to align with the bottom of the image without living a ~20px area below it. The code to see what I mean is below.

HTML:

```
    <div id="links">
    <a href="#" class="links">Link1</a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link2</a>
    <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/350x175.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="links">Link3</a>
    <a href="#"class="links">Link4</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#links{
    /* SIZING */
    width:70%;
    min-width:625px;
    min-height:10px;
    /* POSITIONING */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FF0;
}

.links {
    /* DISPLAY */
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border-radius:15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    /* SIZING */
    width:calc(16.25% - 10px);
    height:50px;
    margin:5px;
    /* TEXT */
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:auto;
    color:#000; 
}

#logo{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:0px;
    width:calc(35% - 10px);
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the vertical-align to bottom it will align to the bottom like so;

```
.links {
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(136, 136, 136);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: bottom; //// ADDED STYLE
    width: calc(16.25% - 10px);
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ya2uoe9n/2/)